# Calculation of words, sentences and paragraphs from text entered by the user

Tags: c#

I need to write a program to take an entry 'essay' from the user. This essay can contain any characters (special characters, quotation marks, etc.). It then has to calculate the total number of words, sentences and paragraphs, and the total number of special characters. How should I go about doing this?

Comment: If you want help with your homework, you must show us what you've done and tell us the *specific* problem you have encountered.

Comment: @shashank, this sounds very much like a "homework" question... What code have you written so far to solve this problem, or what problems have you encountered that you need help with? Asking for a solution in its entirety, which is effectively what you've done here, is unlikely to elicit a response

Comment: I remember this assignment from 1601 (Intro to computer science) :)

Comment: There is 1 word, 0 sentences, 0 paragraphs and 0 special characters in `essay`.

Comment: @BoltClock +1 for an awesome comment lol

Answer (score 12):

I can't believe you would expect someone to write a program for you, so I am assuming that you are asking the correct way to tackle the problem.

Break the problem down into smaller, manageable problems:

1) Define what a word is (a string of uninterrupted letters)

2) Work out a way of counting those items (e.g. you could start at the beginning of the input, look for how many interruptions to strings of letters there are)

3) Define what a sentence is (a string of words, ended by a period '.')

4) Work out a way of counting those items (e.g. you could count the number of periods preceeded by at least one word)

And so on.

Comment: Very nice answer, instead of just writing "this is a homework, do it yourself" or voting negative.